# Check the value of a checked checkbox from a group of checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a group of check boxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="v1" name="q_119[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="v2" name="q_119[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="v3" name="q_119[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="v4" name="q_119[]">
```

And I want to check if one particular checkbox has been checked (say the one with `value="v4"`
and if so, add a css class to another element on the page.

I tried to use this code:

```
$('input[name="119[]"]').click(function(){
    if ($('input[value="v1"]:checked'))
    {
        {
            $('#qu_120').removeClass('hide');
        } 
        else
        {
            $('#qu_120').addClass('hide');
        } 
    }
});
```

But the class is not applied when the checkbox is checked. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fXKFp/2/) is the jsFiddle of my efforts

Comment: Shorter version: http://jsfiddle.net/Gjyb7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just misspelled in your `selector`. Check the name.

Try,

```
$('input[name="q_119[]"]').click(function(){
    if ($('input[value="v1"]').is(':checked'))
    {
       $('#qu_120').removeClass('hide');
    } 
    else
    {
       $('#qu_120').addClass('hide');
    } 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/fXKFp/4/)

Comment: ohhhhh my god, I've been staring at this for ages -  I can't believe it was a misspelled selector. I'm an idiot. Thank you

Comment: His worked but yours didn't because of the the extra braces. Your "else" statement was now causing an error because there was no corresponding "if". Only, Javascript doesn't know/care about that and tries to execute accordingly, but fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('input[name="q_119[]"]').change(function(){
    if ($('input[value="v1"]').prop('checked')){
            $('#qu_120').removeClass('hide');
    } 
    else{
        $('#qu_120').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXKFp/5/)

Comment: @Gideon because the selector should be `$('input[name="q_119[]"]').click()`.

Comment: Add a `.trigger('change')` at the end. http://jsfiddle.net/fXKFp/7/ Still giving you an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You've got four problems preventing this from working:

```
$('input[name="119[]"]').click(function(){ // name attr is incorrect, should be "q_119[]"
    if ($('input[value="v1"]:checked')) // returns an object, so it will always be true
    { // <- unexpected curly brace
        {
            $('#qu_120').removeClass('hide');
        } 
        else
        {
            $('#qu_120').addClass('hide');
        } 
    } // <- unexpected curly brace
});
```

Fixing these...

```
$('input[name="q_119[]"]').click(function () { // name attr is now correct
    if ($('input[value="v1"]:checked').length) { // length is an integer which returns 0 if the selector cannot find the element
        $('#qu_120').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#qu_120').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

and your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fXKFp/8/